# Return values from axios get not from cache

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I wanted to take some data from Axios to get it returns the old values not the new one the data is an article contain some description and  an array of comments but after adding a comment I can fetch it by postman or the browser and gives the new results but in my react app it returns an empty array of comments  I tried using cache header after that it didn't render the old values it stoped from fetching my function looks like this

```
export const getOneDoneArticle = id => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(`/doneArticles/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_DONE_ARTICLE,
        payload: res.data
      });
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: I am suggesting that this is close to be a `cache-control` policy implemented by the API not `axios`. have you considered this? it's a long shot that axios has to do anything with it.

Comment: could you clear up because I didn't understand you

Comment: API's have something called _cashe control policies_, which controls caching options for requests that come from the same REFERRER to the same ROUTE, in this case, your React App is the referrer, and the route is: ``/doneArticles/${id}``. what I am saying, it's possible that this route has caching policy that prevents making data fetch per request, instead returns the latest cached request, it can be cached for the REFERRER, or even the SESSION it self.